# making it sound like a record player

Tags: music, dialogue

Hey guys, I am currently working on a project where I need to make music sound as if it is playing from a record player, and then separately I need to make some dialogue sound like its coming from a gramophone, has any body got an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

If you're on Nuendo, then there's a plugin for that: Grungelizer. It's really good!

If not, you can download [iZotope Vinyl](http://www.izotope.com/products/audio/vinyl/), it's free. Never tried it but looks really nice.

Comment: I've used Izotope Vinyl and can vouch for it - it should do the trick nicely. Additionally, you could try running the processed music/dialogue through a reverb or worldize it, if it's supposed to sound like it's coming from a player within a space.

Comment: Thanks guys, have been trying the izotope vinyl and is doing the trick 

Comment: In addition to iZotope Vinyl, you can try the plastic speaker setting in MDA Combo (from http://mda.smartelectronix.com/).  It may be too harsh, but I've found it useful from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

You could also demo the Speakerphone from AudioEase. Good for other stuff too... :)